# put windows 8 back on linux laptop

Tags: 14.04

I had windows 8.1 on my laptop, and I tried to upgrade to windows 10, which broke it. I put Ubuntu 14.04 on it (wiping out everything else) and I would like to go back to windows 8.1. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Use the normal methods Windows allows you to use to install their operating system. What those are makes this a Windows related question. Use a DVD. Or a USB if Windows can be installed that way. Or use a restore partition.

Comment: For the ISO: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8

Comment: UEFI or BIOS, instructions are different.

Answer (score 0):

Use the windows installation disk provided to you with the laptop or buy a windows disk or download a windows version . Install the normal way and you'll have windows in place of ubuntu

Comment: It will replace Ubuntu or live alongside it? Also, I only have about 30gb of space on my hard drive, so I need to conserve all the space I can.

Comment: You'll replace it

Comment: Okay thanks. I just got a win10 laptop, and I had to do the same thing withe it, just win10... it broke straight out of the box literally.